# How to send a message to local SQS queue using python boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to emulate AWS SQS functionality using https://github.com/roribio/alpine-sqs container.

I was able to run the docker container and send the messages to the queue using terminal. configured **AWS Access Key ID** and **AWS Secret Access Key** to empty strings using `aws configure`

The command I used to send the message to the SQS queue container is this

```
aws --endpoint-url http://localhost:9324 sqs send-message --queue-url http://localhost:9324/queue/default --message-body "Hello, queue!"
```

I was able to receive the message and I can see it in the dashboad in browser at `localhost:9235`.

But when I try to send the message using `boto3` in `python`, it is throwing an error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/infomagnus/PycharmProjects/InfoMagnus/workload/app/workload/services/queue_services.py",
>   line 13, in 
>       'Information about current NY Times fiction bestseller for '   File
>   "/home/infomagnus/envs/DSDPenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py",
>   line 357, in _api_call
>       return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)   File "/home/infomagnus/envs/DSDPenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py",
>   line 661, in _make_api_call
>       raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name) botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred
>   (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the SendMessage operation: The
>   security token included in the request is invalid

Not sure why I'm getting the error even after setting the keys using `aws configure`.

Everything that I'm running is in my local.

Here's my code:

```
import boto3
sqs = boto3.client('sqs', aws_access_key_id=None, aws_secret_access_key=None)
queue_url = 'http://localhost:9324/queue/default'
resp = sqs.send_message(
    QueueUrl=queue_url,
    MessageBody=(
        'Sample message for Queue.'
    )
)
print(resp['MessageId'])
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot to pass `endpoint_url`.

```
sqs = boto3.client('sqs', aws_access_key_id=None, aws_secret_access_key=None, endpoint_url='http://localhost:9324')
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this example here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-sqs-message_wrapper.py.html). Check out this script to upload minibatches of N=10 size:

```py
import json
import boto3
from tqdm import tqdm
from more_itertools import ichunked

QUEUE_URL = "<your_queue_url>"
client = boto3.client('sqs')

def send_messages(messages):
    entries = [{
        'Id': str(ind),
        'MessageBody': json.dumps({
            # Your body goes here
        })
    } for ind, obj in enumerate(messages)]

    response = client.send_message_batch(QueueUrl=QUEUE_URL, Entries=entries)
    if 'Failed' in response:
        raise Exception(f"Error in messages: {response}")
    return response

def enqueue_messages(batch_size=10):
    for chunk in tqdm(ichunked(your_generator(), batch_size)):
        send_messages(chunk)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    enqueue_messages()
```